# Combining text-overflow:ellipsis with display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'd like to use `display: flex;` for centering while also having a `...` overflow when text overflows. It seems that as soon as I introduce the `display: flex`, the ellipsis stops working. Any suggestions on how to combine these two? JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/silverwind/sw78h02b/1/

```css
.target {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: flex; /* remove this to get ellipsis to show */
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  Text here is very very long that it will overflow the width of the containing element. Adding another sentence to make sure it will overflow.
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

Put your text inside `span` and use `display: flex` on parent and text-overflow on span.

```css
.target {
  background: red;
  margin: 2rem;
  display: flex; 
}
span {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="target">
  <span>Text here is very very long that it will overflow the width of the containing element. Adding another sentence to make sure it will overflow.</span>
</div>
```